# Код не проходит тесты

Tags: c++, олимпиада, простые-числа, теория-чисел

Задача довольно простая, отсюда http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1086

Решил, просто посчитав решето эратосфена до числа, где порядковый номер последнего простого числа 15 000. На моем компе все работает (смотри скриншот), а на сайте заваливает даже 1 тест. На форуме сборника задач не отвечают. Что делать, не знаю... Может, подкинете варианты входных данных, на которых я могу словить ошибку?

Скриншот:

[image]

Код:

```
bool *eratosthen(){
    bool *arr = new bool[LIMIT+1];

    arr[1] = 1;
    for(unsigned int i=2; i<=LIMIT; i++){
        if(arr[i] == false){
            for(unsigned int k = i*i; k<=LIMIT; k+=i)
                arr[k] = 1;
        }
    }


    return arr;
}
unsigned int searchPrimeNumbers(bool *arr, int num){
    unsigned int count = 0, curr = 0;

    while(++curr <= LIMIT){
        if(arr[curr] == 0){
            count++;
        }
        if(count == num){
            return curr;            
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    // FILE *file = freopen("input.txt", "rt", stdin); //при сдаче эта строка закоменчена
    bool *result = eratosthen();
        int n;
    cin >> n; //сколько всего чисел
    while(cin >> n){
        if(n == 0){ // для нуля выводим нуль
            cout << "0" << "\n";
            continue;
        }
        cout << searchPrimeNumbers(result, n) << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Решается в свободное время, не является учебным заданием.

**Обновление:**

В попытках найти ошибку я решил взять эталонный набор простых чисел и сравнить их с моими:

[image]

Слева эталон, справа мое. Как исправить ошибку?

**Обновление_2:**

Смещение на 1 появилось из-за предела возможного числа unsigned int. Странно другое. Исправив так, что все сходится с эталонными числами, я все равно не прохожу тесты. Wrong answer и все.  :*(

Кстати, в алгоритме допущена была ошибка: в первом цикле не `i<=LIMIT`, а `i*i<=LIMIT`, поскольку проходить значения выше чем `sqrt(LIMIT)` не имеет смысла. Если это исправить, то unsigned int хватает.

Comment: Парни, я так не понял, почему не могу пройти тесты. Вроде все ок должно быть.

Comment: В реализацию не вникал, но в строке "if(arr[i] == false){" вы читаете из неинициализированного элемента на первой же итерации (когда i == 2).

Comment: Вы у себя дома запускаете программу под отладчиком, который заполняет нулями неинициализированную память. А тестирующая система компилирует релизный код, который оставляет мусор в неинициализированной памяти.

Answer (score 1):

А чему у вас равно `LIMIT`? Может быть, текст проваливается из-за того, что `LIMIT` маленький?

Comment: \#define LIMIT 163953

Там где-то рядышком 15 000 простое число по порядку. Я проверял - оно укладывалось.
Вобщем я уже забил на это. Ну не проходит и ладно :( Главное, что вроде работает.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, уже неактуально :), но главная проблема - кто вам вообще сказал, что во входе будет ровно столько строк, какое число в первой строке? Вы читаете файл *до конца*, а надо именно `k` значений...

Кстати, **update** через 4.5 года :) — вот такое забавное решение, основанное на разности простых чисел, вполне сработало...

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int primas[] = {
    0,1,2,2,4,2,4,2,4,6,2,6,4,2,4,6,6,2,6,4,2,6,4,6,8,4,

    ....

    6,6,28,12,8,6,6,4,6,18,12,6,18,32,4,8,12,18,10,8,22,8,22,6
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int Q;
        cin >> Q;
        int P = 2;
        for(int j = 0; j < Q; ++j) P += primas[j];
        cout << P << endl;
    }
}
```